# Predicate logic: Someone visited the same mall every day in September

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

The full question is:

Let P(x, y, z) be the predicate "Person x visited y on z", where the domain of x is all the people in the country, the domain of y is all the malls in the country, and the domain of z is all the days in the month of September. Express the following using propositions, predicates, and quantifiers:

1. Someone visited the same mall every day in September
2. There are at least two persons who visited Mall A on 30th September

Here are my answers so far:

1. ∃x∃y∀zP(x, y, z)
2. Let person 1 be x1 and person 2 be x2

   ∃x∃y∃z(x1 ≠ x2 ∧ P(x1, mall A, 30th September) ∧ P(x2, mall A, 30th September))

My answers were marked partially incorrect, but I'm not sure what's missing.

For part 1, my professor mentioned to include an "AND" condition and another variable q in the domain of malls for part 1, so as to indicate that x does not visit any other mall besides y.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Just quickly:  note that for your solution to $2$, you quantify $x,y,z$ but none of those appear in your statement.

Comment: Your answer to part 1 is correct.  Your answer to part two is poorly worded.  In particular, you wrote $\exists x$ in your part two answer, however $x$ does not do anything.  Meanwhile you in words wrote something about "person 1 be $x_1$" and such but that should have been a part of the statement below.  Similarly, you wrote $\exists y\exists z$ which again you aren't using such a $y$ and $z$ in the rest.

Comment: It should have been for part (2) written as $\exists x_1 \exists x_2~(x_1\neq x_2\wedge P(x_1,\text{Mall }A,\text{30th September})\wedge P(x_2,\text{Mall }A,\text{30th September})$.  Mention of $x,y,z$ unnecessary and existence of such a choice for $x_1,x_2$ should have been a part of the statement itself.

Comment: @JMoravitz I see, thank you! I apologize, but I forgot to include that my professor mentioned including an "AND" condition and another variable q in the domain of malls for part 1, so as to indicate that x does not visit any other mall besides y. I'm not quite sure how that would be written.

Comment: With the originally phrased problem, there is no reason to include that condition.  A person can visit multiple malls within the same day.  Why wouldn't they be able to?  As for writing the statement "There is someone who visited some mall every day in september and visited no other malls in that time" that would be something like $\exists x\exists y_1 \forall y_2 \forall z (P(x,y_1,z) \wedge (y_1=y_2\vee \neg P(x,y_2,z))$